# How to Prevent Anemone from Storing Certain Information?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, web-scraping, web-crawler

I'm using [Anemone](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/) for some web spidering.  I'm storing the results of the spidering in MongoDB.  Anemone makes it very easy to do this with:

```
  Anemone.crawl("http://www.example.com/") do |anemone|
    anemone.storage = Anemone::Storage.MongoDB
  end
```

as [specified here](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/information-and-examples.html#storage).

However, using the code above, Anemone collects and stores a lot of information that I don't need, including each page's response.  I only need to store URLs.  And, despite spending time with [the documentation](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/doc/index.html), I can't figure out how to tell Anemone *not* to store certain pieces of info.

Can anyone advise?

Comment: The "How do I use it?" section on the [main rubyforge project page](http://anemone.rubyforge.org/index.html) seems to be heading in the right direction for your needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to adjust the Page class so that it doesn't store the extra data. So something like:

```
module Anemone
  class Page
    def to_hash
      {'url' => @url.to_s,
       'links' => links.map(&:to_s),
       'code' => @code,
       'visited' => @visited,
       'depth' => @depth,
       'referer' => @referer.to_s,
       'fetched' => @fetched}
    end
    def self.from_hash(hash)
      page = self.new(URI(hash['url']))
      {'@links' => hash['links'].map { |link| URI(link) },
       '@code' => hash['code'].to_i,
       '@visited' => hash['visited'],
       '@depth' => hash['depth'].to_i,
       '@referer' => hash['referer'],
       '@fetched' => hash['fetched']
      }.each do |var, value|
        page.instance_variable_set(var, value)
      end
      page
    end
  end
end
Anemone.crawl("http://www.example.com/") do |anemone|
  anemone.storage = Anemone::Storage.MongoDB
end
```

It's been a while since I've looked at the internals but if I remember correctly, the Page needs to contain the links, depth, fetched and some of the other meta-data so it knows what it has already crawled and what it has left to do.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

In Rails 3.0.10 with ruby 1.9.2 it seems you have to use an initilizer.

config/initilizers/anemone.rb

```
Anemone::Page.module_eval do
  def to_hash
    {'url' => @url.to_s,
     'links' => links.map(&:to_s),
     'code' => @code,
     'visited' => @visited,
     'depth' => @depth,
     'referer' => @referer.to_s,
     'redirect_to' => @redirect_to.to_s,
     'response_time' => @response_time,
     'fetched' => @fetched}
  end

  def self.from_hash(hash)
    page = self.new(URI(hash['url']))
    {'@links' => hash['links'].map { |link| URI(link) },
     '@visited' => hash['visited'],
     '@code' => hash['code'].to_i,
     '@depth' => hash['depth'].to_i,
     '@referer' => hash['referer'],
     '@redirect_to' => URI(hash['redirect_to']),
     '@response_time' => hash['response_time'].to_i,
     '@fetched' => hash['fetched']
    }.each do |var, value|
      page.instance_variable_set(var, value)
    end
    page
  end
end
```